# Xamarin ListView spinner goes away too soon for asynchronous command

Tags: xamarin, asynchronous, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin.Forms list view that I want to refresh on pull:

```xml
<ListView x:Name="listView"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Announcements}"
      HasUnevenRows="true"
      IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
      IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}">
```

Code-behind:

```cs
private bool isRefreshing = false;
public bool IsRefreshing
{
    get { return isRefreshing; }
    set
    {
        isRefreshing = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsRefreshing));
    }
}

private void SetListViewToRefreshOnPull()
{
    listView.RefreshCommand = new Command(async () =>
    {
        IsRefreshing = true;
        await RefreshData; // After awaiting here, the spinner changes appearance.
        IsRefreshing = false;
    });
}

private Task RefreshData => Task.Delay(5000);
```

Of course, I made the refresh command wait 5 seconds to simulate a slow API response.

Pulling the list view down shows the spinner as expected:

[image]

However, as soon as the `RefreshData` task begins waiting 5 seconds, the spinner goes to a weird "deformed" state that doesn't spin:

[image]

The full spinner is only shown for a split second before the deformed one, so this behavior is not ideal. **Is there any way to get the full spinner to stay for the entire duration of an asynchronous refresh?**

Comment: this is Xamarin Forms, not Xamarin Android

Comment: Update your RefreshData method to be asyn .... private async Task RefreshData => 
await Task.Delay(5000); ...Check updating method to async does have any effect

Comment: Try setting IsRefreshing to false at the end of your asynchronous logic.

Comment: @HamidShaikh, That's not valid code, but I made the command an async method instead a property, and I get the same odd behavior.

Comment: @SparshaBhattara, I'm already setting `IsRefreshing`. The problem seems to be that the framework is prematurely leaving the refresh state. Anyway, I moved the `IsRefreshing = false` assignment to the `RefreshData` async method, which gave the same odd behavior, so I'm still stuck.

Comment: Have you tried changing the IsRefreshing property within the UI thread using Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread method? Seems like your UI is blocked and not executing on the main thread.

Comment: @SparshaBhattarai, I just tried that and `Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync()` and other ways of refreshing asynchronously (e.g. `Task.Run()`), but they all give the same behavior. It seems like whenever the refresh command hits the first `await`, it changes the spinner's appearance. It seems like I can't both avoid blocking the UI thread and also keep the full spinner showing the entire time. I would have thought I'd find more googling this, because I'd think most refreshes would have to be asynchronous in the real world.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't reproduce this question.Could you please share a basic demo which could produce this qusestion so that we can test with it?

Comment: @JessieZhang, I'll try to add a complete demo later this week. It's possible it happens only for certain Android versions. I'm testing on Android 8.0.

Comment: @thatWiseGuy I tested on android 8.0, it also worked properly.

Comment: Did you try Task.Run(async () => { await Task.Delay(5000); IsRefreshing = true; })?

Comment: @iSpain17, Yes, it doesn't work. I'm starting to think the behavior I'm looking for isn't supported in Android, because I'm seeing the same issue for a loading indicator in another popular app.

Comment: Well, if it's convenient, being able to upload a demo is the fastest way to solve the problem. :)

Answer (score -2):

Try `IsRefreshing = false` which should hide the loading indicator.

Comment: I'm already doing this, and the problem is not that I can't get the loading indicator to hide; the problem is that I can't get the full spinner to stay up the entire time.

Comment: Yes, i got it. It's the default behavior of android. You can't hold its visibility. However, you can change its colour using custom render. What you are trying to achieve is default behavior of iOS.